# Executing a sqlalchemy exists query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, exists

I'm having trouble understanding how to execute a query to check and see if a matching record already exists in sqlalchemy.  Most of the examples I can find online seem to reference "session" and "query" objects that I don't have.

Here's a short complete program that illustrates my problem:
1. sets up in-memory sqlite db with "person" table.
2. inserts two records into the person table.
3. check if a particular record exists in the table.  This is where it barfs.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import exists

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
metadata = MetaData()

person = Table('person', metadata,
                        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                        Column('name', String(255), nullable=False))

metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

s = person.insert()
conn.execute(s, name="Alice")
conn.execute(s, name="Bob")

print("I can see the names in the table:")
s = person.select()
result = conn.execute(s)
print(result.fetchall())

print('This query looks like it should check to see if a matching record exists:')
s = person.select().where(person.c.name == "Bob")
s = exists(s)
print(s)

print("But it doesn't run...")
result = conn.execute(s)
```

The output of this program is:

```
I can see the names in the table:
[(1, 'Alice'), (2, 'Bob')]
This query looks like it should check to see if a matching record exists:
EXISTS (SELECT person.id, person.name 
FROM person 
WHERE person.name = :name_1)
But it doesn't run...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/project_path/db_test/db_test_env/exists_example.py", line 30, in <module>
    result = conn.execute(s)
  File "/project_path/db_test/db_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/project_path/db_test/db_test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 265, in _execute_on_connection
    raise exc.ObjectNotExecutableError(self)
sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: <sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Exists object at 0x105797438>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The s.exists() is only building the exists clause.  All you need to do to get your code to work is to generate a select for it.

```
s = exists(s).select()
```

Here's your full example:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import exists

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=False)
metadata = MetaData()

person = Table('person', metadata,
                        Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
                        Column('name', String(255), nullable=False))

metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

s = person.insert()
conn.execute(s, name="Alice")
conn.execute(s, name="Bob")

print("I can see the names in the table:")
s = person.select()
result = conn.execute(s)
print(result.fetchall())

print('This query looks like it should check to see if a matching record exists:')
s = person.select().where(person.c.name == "Bob")
s = exists(s).select()
print(s)

print("And it runs fine...")
result = conn.execute(s)
print(result.fetchall())
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I wanted!  I was so close, I just couldn't figure out how to wrap that extra select on.  Thank you.

Only minor change I might make is:
`result = conn.execute(s).scalar()`
so we just get back the basic True / False instead of a result row.

Answer (score 1):

`exists` is used in SQL subqueries.  If you had a table `posts` containing blog post with an author_id, mapping back to people, you might use a query like the following to find people who had made a blog post:

```
select * from people where exists (select author_id from posts where author_id = people.id);
```

You can't have a exists as the outermost statement in an SQL query; it's an operator to use in SQL boolean clauses.
So, SQLAlchemy is not letting you execute that query because it's not well-formed.
If you want to see if a row exists, just construct a select statement with a where clause and see how many rows the query returns.

Comment: Thanks, Sam, but I would think there would have to be a better way.  I don't want to transfer what could potentially be lots of matching rows from the db, I just want to transfer the true or false scalar value.

Comment: Add a `limit 1` to your query.  That's what I've seen a lot of web apps do.

Comment: "You can't have a exists as the outermost statement in an SQL query" Why not? According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html and testing, of course you can!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
...
s = person.select().where(person.c.name == "Bob")
s = select(exists(s))
print(s)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone suggests a better answer, here's what I've come up with that works.  Having the DB count the matching records and send just the count to the python app.

```
from sqlalchemy import select, func   # more imports not in my example code above

s = select([func.count(1)]).select_from(person).where(person.c.name == "Bob")
print(s)
record_count = conn.execute(s).scalar()
print("Matching records: ", record_count)
```

Example output:

```
SELECT count(:count_2) AS count_1 
FROM person 
WHERE person.name = :name_1
Matching records:  1
```