# SQLAlchemy - MySQL - Check if row exists in existing table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have simple setup with SQLAlchemy currently it's setup to connect with existing database like this:

```
self.users = db.Table('users', self.metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=self.engine)
```

It connects to existing table, but I don't know how to check for existing row when I connect to table when it's not created by SQLAlchemy.

What I've tried:

```
session.query(self.users.query.filter(self.users.id == 1).exists()).scalar()
```

I got that Table object doesn't have attribute query

Answer (score 0):

Your error means the `Table` object does not have a `query` attribute because SQLAlchemy has an separate `Query` API.

See this post [How to query a table, in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618690/how-to-query-a-table-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: It's an existing table without base and that answer is from 2010

Answer (score 0):

Alright for everybody wondering solution is following:

1. Option

   ```
    check_existing = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.username == "admin")
    check_existing_result = session.execute(check_existing).fetchall()

    if len(check_existing_result) == 0:
        print('empty')
    else:
        print('found')
   ```
2. Option

   ```
    query = session.query(self.users).all()

    for obj in query:
        if obj[1] == 'admin':
            print('true')
   ```
3. Option

   ```
    check_existing = self.users.select().where(self.users.c.username == "admin")
    check_existing_result = session.execute(check_existing).scalar()

        if check_existing_result == None:
            print('empty')
        else:
            print('true')
   ```

Thanks to [Executing a sqlalchemy exists query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360622/executing-a-sqlalchemy-exists-query)